# Write a function named containsLetter that identifies all of the strings in a list that contain a specified letter and returns a list of those strings

Tags: python, for-loop, parameters, function

```
searchLetter = str(input("Enter a Letter: ")
hulkLine= ["you", "wouldn't", "like", "me", "when", "i'm", "angry"]                   
def containsLetter(searchLetter, hulkLine):
    for x in range(hulkLine -1):
            if hulkLine[x] == 't':
```

I am posting the correct output of the function below.

The function `containsLetter()` takes two parameters:

1. a string of length 1, `aLetter`
2. a list of strings, `strList`

For example, the following would be correct output:

```
>>> hulkLine = ["you", "wouldn't", "like", "me", "when", "i'm", "angry"] 
>>> searchLetter = 'i' 
>>> print(containsLetter(searchLetter, hulkLine)) 
>>> ["like", "i'm"]
```

Comment: You can't subtract an `int` from a `list`. Try `for x in range(len(hulkLine)-1)`. Also, to test if a character is in a string, use the `in` operator

Comment: Question copied directly from Problem 12 Part A of this NJIT practice midterm. http://web.njit.edu/~theo/courses/cs100/fall2014/cs100_2014F_practice_midterm1.pdf

Comment: yes that is true i copied the question because i am working on that exam for my class

Comment: Stackoverflow is not your personal homework answer site

Comment: who said personal site i said i did the work but not getting the answer that's why i posted the question here so i can understand my mistake in my problem okey if want to help student then help either just dont comment at all. thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ok ?

```
>>> def containsLetter(searchLetter, hulkLine):
...     return [x for x in hulkLine if searchLetter in x]
...
>>> containsLetter('i', hulkLine)
['like', "i'm"]
>>>
```

Or

```
>>> filter(lambda x: searchLetter in x, hulkLine)
['like', "i'm"]
>>>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but when i am trying to run the code the way you posted i get my mistake but i am getting syntax error for hulkLine = ['you', 'wouldn't', 'like', 'me', 'when','when','i'm','angry'] can you suggest me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you change this one : "i'm", btw what is the error.

Comment: its says that syntax error when i run the program

Comment: are you working on which python version